# Use different .htaccess file based on set header from browser

Tags: htaccess, apache2, http-headers

I want to have the ability to test *.htaccess* rules before saving them to the main *.htaccess* file.

Is it possible to set a specific request header and have Apache use a set of rules from a different *.htaccess* file.

Comment: Yes, I know that you can/should use development sites/environments for testing these types of changes, but am asking because the thought occurred to me that I might be able to do this as well. Using ".htaccess" inside quotes because the name of the secondary file name would obviously not be able to be .htaccess

Comment: Start with [this guide](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html)

Answer (score 2):

This may be possible with Apache 2.4's new features which includes <If>, <ElseIf> and <Else> directives.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

Possible example:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
<If "$req{Host} != 'test.mydomain.com'">
    AccessFileName .htaccess_test
</If>
```

For older versions I am not aware of any such options. Perhaps using SetEnvIf would work.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Host "^test\.mydomain\.com$" htaccess_file_name=.htaccess_test
SetEnvIf Remote_Host "^www\.mydomain\.com$" htaccess_file_name=.htaccess
AccessFileName htaccess_file_name
```

I haven't tried this so I can't say that it will actually work at all but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to _change_ the `AccessFileName` per request since this directive needs to go in httpd.conf (or a virtual host context) and is therefore not executed on each request. However, you could perhaps execute different sections within the same .htaccess file, depending on the request (using `<if>` on Apache 2.4 - as you suggest), or perhaps `<IfDefine>` on earlier versions of Apache?

Comment: Yes this would require editing the httpd.conf or related virtual host config. When I have a chance I will test this out to be sure. I don't think it is possible with any versions prior to 2.4 though. I do know that using SetEnvIf variables wont work with <IfDefine>, unfortunately.

Comment: "is therefore not executed on each request" - Sorry, I'm not sure what I was thinking there, that is obviously not correct. However, I was just trying to have a go with this myself but (for some reason) I'm unable to set `AccessFileName` conditionally inside an `<If>` block? I'm simply unable to restart the server (unhelpful error). I can set `AccessFileName` outside of the `<If>` block and use other directives inside the `<If>` block, but not `AccessFileName`? Did you manage to test this?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to get back and post a reply. I had the same problem with apache complaining that AccessFileName couldn't be used inside the <If> block. I think the only viable solution is to create a testing virtual host domain that is pointed at the same document root and set the AccessFileName to something else in that vhost configuration.